# Python 3: is there any need of using unicode_escape encoding?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode

[This link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings) lists out some python specific encodings.

One of the encoding is "unicode_escape".

I am just trying to figure out, is this special encoding really needed?

```
>>> l = r'C:\Users\userx\toot'
>>> l
'C:\\Users\\userx\\toot'
>>> l.encode('unicode_escape').decode()
'C:\\\\Users\\\\userx\\\\toot'
```

If you could see above, 'l' which is a unicode object, has already taken care of escaping the backslashes. Converting it to "unicode_escape" encoding adds one more set of escaped backslashes which doesn't make any sense to me.

Questions:

1. Is "unicode_escape" encoding really needed?
2. why did "unicode_escape" added one more sets of backslashes above?

Comment: If you `print(l)` you'll see that in the actual content of the string, the backslashes are not escaped. The `repr` version of a string escapes backslashes in order to show it unambiguously to you, the developer.

Comment: Why do you think `unicode_escape()` *is* or *would be* needed for your use case? Just because something exists doesn't mean it's meaningful or relevant to you.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i am writing a python script which takes a windows style path as an argument. As such the script is working without any issues. i just wanted to make sure are there any cases where in i have to convert the arg input using "unicode_escape"?

Comment: The purpose of `unicode_escape()` is to generate content that can be substituted directly into a plain-ASCII Python source file. You aren't doing that, so you don't need it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Could you give me an example where one has to "generate content that can be substituted directly into a plain-ASCII Python source file"?

Comment: Hmm. I could potentially see needing to do that if you were writing a Python decompiler (though the existing ones are just as likely to implement that functionality directly themselves as to use what the library provides). I've also seen code-generation used for template engine generation, though more recent/modern examples build AST trees, not textual source.

Comment: Frankly, though, "how can X be used?" is a completely open-ended question, and we don't allow those here. Questions need to be specific, and based on an actual problem that you face.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Got it! Thanks for the example though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [the document you linked](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings):

> Encoding suitable as the contents of a Unicode literal in ASCII-encoded Python source code, except that quotes are not escaped. Decodes from Latin-1 source code. Beware that Python source code actually uses UTF-8 by default.

Thus, `print(l.encode('unicode_escape').decode())` does something *almost exactly equivalent to* `print(repr(l))`, except that it doesn't add quotes on the outside and escape quotes on the inside of the string.

When you leave off the `print()`, the REPL does a default `repr()`, so you get backslashes escaped twice -- exactly the same thing as happens when you run `>>> repr(l)`.